# Blocking on UIImageView animation, or, "while not finished animating, spin"

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview

I'm currently animating many images via 4 UIImageViews, and all is well on that front.  The animations complete as expected, and I am assuming that they run inside their own NSThread, as execution continues despite the animation.  Of course, this is good and expected behaviour, as I definitely wouldn't want my whole app to halt until the animation finishes.

However, I need to kick off a method which needs to depend on whether the animation is running or not.

The following code is bad as I understand, as introducing loops and other delays inside the main thread causes instability.

```
while([self.fooImgView isAnimating])
        ;
```

This code effectively halts execution of the whole app.  I need to find a way to "spin" until the animation completes, without wedging the app.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

sc.

Comment: Have you tried KVO? I'm not sure if UIImageView is KVO-compliant.

Comment: @jtbandes - hadn't seen that before, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you use block animations [like this one](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3adelay%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a), you can use the completion block to call some delegate or execute your method

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about block animations.  I may need to switch from the "simple" UIImageView animations to block, as it does seem to provide more granular controls.